# Records shuffles in 2 columns in GridView in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

I am working with Custom GridView where I am having 2 columns of images.
When I scroll the Grid down to the next records and returns to the first row of records, my records got shuffle with in a row from its position.

Means, the **GridView** Records shuffle from one column to another record when the view regenerate in **getview()**.

Please suggest me.

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LinkedList<GalleryFeed> imagesLinkedList = new LinkedList<GalleryFeed>();
        private Context mContext = null;
        private LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = null;
        private ImageLoader _feedLoader = null;
        /**
         * 
         * @param localContext
         * @param mListItems
         */
        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext,LinkedList<GalleryFeed> mListItems) {
            mContext = localContext;
            this.imagesLinkedList = mListItems;
            _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            _feedLoader = new ImageLoader(DefaultGalleryFrag.this.getActivity().getParent());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imagesLinkedList != null ? imagesLinkedList.size() : 0;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return imagesLinkedList.get(position);
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        public class ViewHolder{
            public ImageView imageView=null;
            public ImageView videoImageView=null;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            GalleryFeed bean = imagesLinkedList.get(position);

            if(convertView == null){
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = linf.inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, null);
                viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
                viewHolder.videoImageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoPalyIV);
                /**
                 * SET THE RESOLUTION PIC ON IMAGE VIEW
                 */
                if(bean.getMediaType()!=null && bean.getMediaType().equalsIgnoreCase("Image")){
                    if(bean.getResolution280()!=null && bean.getResolution280().length()>0){
                        File imgFile = new File(bean.getResolution280());
                        if(imgFile.exists()&& imgFile.length()>0){
                            Bitmap myBitmap = Constant.getBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                            if(myBitmap!=null){
                                viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getResolution280());
                                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),myBitmap);
                                viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
                            }else{
                                _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution280(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                            }
                        }else{
                            _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution280(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                        }
                    }else{
                        _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution280(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                    }
                    viewHolder.videoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    /**
                     * IF ITS A VIDEO FEED
                     */
                    viewHolder.videoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //_feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getVideoFrame(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                    viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile_pic);
                }
                /*if(mediaLeftForDownload.contains(String.valueOf(position))&& _mediaUrlList!=null &&_mediaUrlList.size()>0){
                    _imageLoader.DisplayImage(_mediaUrlList.get(position), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                }else{
                    viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imagesLinkedList.get(position));
                }*/
                v.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }


            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            DefaultGalleryFrag.this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
            if(screenWidth<500){
                viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(/*new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300)*/ new LayoutParams(200,200));
            }else{
                viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300,300));
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```

As shown in the images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: you are not doing anything if convertView is not null (i.e. if the view is being reused.)

Comment: @njzk2 :So what am I suppose to do if the view is not null ?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewholder pattern works this way, in `getView` :

```
ViewHolder holder = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myLayout, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    // Populate the holder
    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
// Now, populate the views referenced by the viewHolder:
holder.textView.setText("Hello World");
```

The whole idea is that you don't know if convertView is going to be null (i.e. you'll create a new one) or if it is going to be recycled from a previously existing view, hence saving the inflate time.

In your case, you only populate your view when `convertView` is null. You need to move the populating code outside the if clause.

Comment: I have shifted my image setting source according to your suggestion but still its not working. Now all the images overlapping..

Comment: Done with your concept, Just need to tag the views, I have posted my answer for reference. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     */
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LinkedList<GalleryFeed> imagesLinkedList = new LinkedList<GalleryFeed>();
        private Context mContext = null;
        private LayoutInflater _layoutInflater = null;
        private ImageLoader _feedLoader = null;
        /**
         * 
         * @param localContext
         * @param mListItems
         */
        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext,LinkedList<GalleryFeed> mListItems) {
            mContext = localContext;
            this.imagesLinkedList = mListItems;
            _layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            _feedLoader = new ImageLoader(DefaultGalleryFrag.this.getActivity().getParent());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return imagesLinkedList != null ? imagesLinkedList.size() : 0;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return imagesLinkedList.get(position);
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        public class ViewHolder{
            public ImageView imageView=null;
            public ImageView videoImageView=null;
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            GalleryFeed bean = imagesLinkedList.get(position);

            if(convertView == null){
                viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = linf.inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, null);
                viewHolder.imageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
                viewHolder.videoImageView=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoPalyIV);

                v.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            /**
             * SET THE RESOLUTION PIC ON IMAGE VIEW
             */
            if(bean.getMediaType()!=null && bean.getMediaType().equalsIgnoreCase("Image")){
                if(bean.getResolution280()!=null && bean.getResolution280().length()>0){
                    File imgFile = new File(bean.getResolution280());
                    if(imgFile.exists()&& imgFile.length()>0){
                        Bitmap myBitmap = Constant.getBitmap(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        if(myBitmap!=null){
                            viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getResolution280());
                            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),myBitmap);
                            viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
                            viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getMediaId());//===set tag
                        }else{
                            _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution_280_280URL(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                            viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getMediaId());//===set tag
                        }
                    }else{
                        _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution_280_280URL(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                        viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getMediaId());//===set tag
                    }
                }else{
                    _feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getResolution_280_280URL(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                    viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getMediaId());//===set tag
                }
                viewHolder.videoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                /**
                 * IF ITS A VIDEO FEED
                 */
                viewHolder.videoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.imageView.setTag(bean.getMediaId());//===set tag
                //_feedLoader.DisplayImage(bean.getVideoFrame(), R.drawable.loader, viewHolder.imageView);
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(DefaultGalleryFrag.this.getActivity().getParent().getResources(),
                        R.drawable.profile_pic);
                viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            DefaultGalleryFrag.this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
            if(screenWidth<500){
                viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(/*new GridView.LayoutParams(300,300)*/ new LayoutParams(200,200));
            }else{
                viewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300,300));
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
```